# Initializing Combo Box in C# Access

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, combobox

I was trying to add a combo box which could get all the product name but unfortunately I follow some tutorials and end up like this.

```
void fillCombo()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from IblInventory");
            command.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                String product = reader.GetString("ProductName"); // << invalid argument
                cmbProduct.Items.Add(product);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

What could possibly the reason?

Comment: Specify the error, word "error" means nothing.

Comment: I have four columns sir. And can't find the right syntax on the ``reader.GetString()`` I can't run the program because of that

Comment: "I was trying to add a combo box ... but ... end up like this. What could possibly the reason?"  This question is too vague. Please describe in detail what your problem is. What was your expectation? What is not working? If you have some Error messages -> what are they?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [OleDbDataReader.GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will notice that the argument required by the method is an integer representing the position of the column in the returned record not its name.

If you (rightly) prefer to use the column name then you need to take a detour and use the `GetOrdinal` method to retrieve the position of the column given the name.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    int pos = reader.GetOrdinal("ProductName");
    String product = reader.GetString(pos); 
    cmbProduct.Items.Add(product);
}
```

Another example, practically identical to your situation, can be found in the documentation page on MSDN about [OleDbDataReader.GetOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx)

It is also a common practice to write an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that allows you to write code as yours hiding the details of the mapping between name and position. You just need a static class with

```
public static class ReaderExtensions
{
     public string GetString(this OleDbDataReader reader, string colName)
     {
         string result = "";
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(colName))
         {
             int pos = reader.GetOrdinal(colName);
             result = reader.GetString(pos);
         }
         return result;
     }
     ... other extensions for Int, Decimals, DateTime etc...
}
```

Now with this class in place and accessible you can call

```
string product = reader.GetString("ProductName");
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working in my project 
   First fill your data in to datatable see the below code

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();

using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from IblInventory", conn);

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    adapter.Fill(results);
}
```

Now

```
cmbProduct.DataSource = results ;
cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
cmbProduct.ValueMember = "Id feild of IblInventory table";
```